# gtk python expanding content to fit window

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have this program and, as much as I try I can not make the elements expand to occupy the area defined for the tire size of the application.

Code:

```
import smtpClass
import xmlHostes
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk



class Base:

def get_main_menu(self, window):
    accel_group = gtk.AccelGroup()
    item_factory = gtk.ItemFactory(gtk.MenuBar, "<main>", accel_group)
    item_factory.create_items(self.menu_items)
    window.add_accel_group(accel_group)
    self.item_factory = item_factory
    return item_factory.get_widget("<main>")

def __init__(self):

    ## MENU CONTENT
    self.menu_items = (#  MENU TREE      # CONTROL KEY   # FUNCTION
                       ( "/_File",          None,         None,             0,  "<Branch>" ),
                       ( "/File/_Setings",  "<control>S", None,             0,  None ),
                       ( "/File/Quit",      "<control>Q", gtk.main_quit,    0,  None ),
                       ( "/_Help",          None,         None,             0,  "<LastBranch>" ),
                       ( "/_Help/About",    None,         None,             0,  None ),
                       )


    # WINDOW WIDGET
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.set_title("pyAnonMail")
    self.window.set_size_request(500, 500)

    # CONTEINER DATA
    main_vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 5)
    #main_vbox.set_border_width(1)
    self.window.add(main_vbox)
    main_vbox.show()

    self.contentTable = gtk.Table(1, 3, True)
    main_vbox.pack_start(self.contentTable, True, True, 10)

    # ADD MENU TO CONTEINER
    self.menubar = self.get_main_menu(self.window)
    main_vbox.add(self.menubar)
    self.menubar.show()

    # FRAME 1 ##########################################################
    self.frame1 = gtk.Frame()
    self.contentTable.attach(self.frame1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    self.frame1.set_label_align(0.0, 0.0)
    self.frame1.set_label("Enter message data")
    self.frame1.set_shadow_type(gtk.SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT)
    self.frame1.show()


    # DATA TABLE

    dataTable = gtk.Table(2, 6, False)
    self.frame1.add(dataTable)
    dataTable.show()

    senderNameFrame = gtk.Label("Sender Name:")
    dataTable.attach(senderNameFrame, 0, 1, 0, 1,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    senderNameFrame.show()
    senderNameEntry = gtk.Entry()
    dataTable.attach(senderNameEntry, 0, 1, 1, 2,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    senderNameEntry.show()

    senderEmailFrame = gtk.Label("Sender Email:")
    dataTable.attach(senderEmailFrame, 1, 2, 0, 1,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    senderEmailFrame.show()
    senderEmailEntry = gtk.Entry()
    dataTable.attach(senderEmailEntry, 1, 2, 1, 2,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    senderEmailEntry.show()

    recipientNameFrame = gtk.Label("Recipient Name:")
    dataTable.attach(recipientNameFrame, 0, 1, 2, 3,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    recipientNameFrame.show()
    recipientNameEntry = gtk.Entry()
    dataTable.attach(recipientNameEntry, 0, 1, 3, 4,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    recipientNameEntry.show()

    recipientEmailFrame = gtk.Label("Recipient Email:")
    dataTable.attach(recipientEmailFrame, 1, 2, 2, 3,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    recipientEmailFrame.show()
    recipientEmailEntry = gtk.Entry()
    dataTable.attach(recipientEmailEntry, 1, 2, 3, 4,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    recipientEmailEntry.show()

    dataAndTimeFrame = gtk.Label("Data and Time:")
    dataTable.attach(dataAndTimeFrame, 0, 1, 4, 5,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    dataAndTimeFrame.show()
    dataAndTimeEntry = gtk.Entry()
    dataTable.attach(dataAndTimeEntry, 1, 2, 4, 5,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    dataAndTimeEntry.show()

    subjectFrame = gtk.Label("Subject:")
    dataTable.attach(subjectFrame, 0, 1, 5, 6,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    subjectFrame.show()
    subjectEntry = gtk.Entry()
    dataTable.attach(subjectEntry, 1, 2, 5, 6,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    subjectEntry.show()

    ####################################################################

    # FRAME 2 ##########################################################
    self.frame2 = gtk.Frame()
    self.contentTable.attach(self.frame2,0,1,1,2,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    self.frame2.set_label_align(0.0, 0.0)
    self.frame2.set_label("Enter message body")
    self.frame2.set_shadow_type(gtk.SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT)
    self.frame2.show()

    table = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    table.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)
    text = gtk.TextView()
    text.set_editable(True)
    textbuffer = text.get_buffer()
    self.frame2.add(table)
    table.show()
    table.add(text)
    text.show()



    ####################################################################

    # FRAME 3 ##########################################################
    self.frame3 = gtk.Frame()
    self.contentTable.attach(self.frame3,0,1,2,3,
        gtk.FILL, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
    self.frame3.set_label_align(0.0, 0.0)
    self.frame3.set_label("Select attached files")
    self.frame3.set_shadow_type(gtk.SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT)
    self.frame3.show()

    ####################################################################

    self.contentTable.show()

    self.window.show()

def main(self):
    gtk.main()

def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()
```

I thought the problem was in the gtk.box parameters, or the parameters of gtk.tables. I've tried everything and nothing changes.
In the examples I find on the net about gtk and python, everything is as I have but the result is always different from mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add gtk.EXPAND to the xoptions parameter when calling [**contentTable.attach**](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktable.html#method-gtktable--attach):

```
# FRAME 1 ##########################################################
self.frame1 = gtk.Frame()
self.contentTable.attach(self.frame1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
gtk.FILL | gtk.EXPAND, gtk.EXPAND | gtk.SHRINK | gtk.FILL, 0, 0)
```